# Dimensionality Reduction for Optimally Preserving KNN

Tags: python, dimensionality-reduction, k-nearest-neighbour, manifold-learning

Do any dimensionality reduction techniques find embeddings which optimally preserve the K-nearest neighbors of each point? If no algorithm provably does this, are there algorithms which heuristically achieve this more often than, say, PCA?

I imagine that an algorithm which builds the nearest neighbors graph and then uses this to find a new embedding would do something like this.

(I'd also be interested in a python library implementing any such algorithm)

Comment: Maybe random projections? It has guarantees on the pair-wise distance between points on the projected points. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_projection. You can also look at MDS (Multi dimensional scaling).

Answer (score 1):

Some manifold learning algorithms (Isomap, LLE, LTSA, Hessian Eigenmaps, I think they are collectively called spectral dimensionality reduction) should in principle do this - this is because they actually use $k$NN graph. This results in algorithm that preserves *local* structure rather than *global* one (they aim at distorting smaller distances less than big distances, kind of reverse of what PCA does).

These algorithms share similar structure:

- construct a pairwise distance/similarity matrix $M$
- perform some kind of matrix decomposition on $M$ (like SVD for example).

For *constructing* $M$ these algorithms use neighborhood graph: run $k$NN for some $k$ and then make graph where $x,y$ are connected if $x$ is in $k$-neighborhood of $y$ or vice versa. Then they run an algorithm for finding distances in this graph.